# Testing an Ember.js component using hasBlock

Tags: ember.js, htmlbars

I have this component set up (stripped down to its minimum):

```
<a href={{href}}>{{text}}</a>

{{#if template}}
  <button {{action "toggleSubmenu"}} class="global-nav-toggle-submenu">
    <i class="caret-down"></i>
  </button>
{{/if}}
```

And this test:

```
test('has a toggle button if a submenu is present', function(assert) {
  var component = this.subject({
    template: Ember.HTMLBars.compile('<ul class="global-nav-submenu"></ul>')
  });

  assert.ok(this.$().find('.global-nav-toggle-submenu').length);
});
```

This runs fine, but I get a deprecation notice from Ember:

> Accessing 'template' in `<app-name@component:global-nav-item::ember540>` is deprecated. To determine if a block was specified to `<app-name@component:global-nav-item::ember540>` please use '{{#if hasBlock}}' in the components layout.

When I change the template to use `hasBlock` instead:

```
<a href={{href}}>{{text}}</a>

{{#if hasBlock}}
  <button {{action "toggleSubmenu"}} class="global-nav-toggle-submenu">
    <i class="caret-down"></i>
  </button>
{{/if}}
```

The test fails. Logging `this.$()` to the console shows that the `hbs` template file seems to be ignoring the `template` I'm adding programmatically.

In the test, I've tried swapping out `template` with `block`, `layout`, `hasBlock`, `content`, etc., with no success. I've tried initializing the `subject` with `hasBlock: true` as well.

And the logic runs fine when loading a page in the regular development app that has a block applied:

```
{{#global-nav-item text="Hello" href="#"}}
  Some Content
{{/global-nav-item}}
```

Is there some other way that I should be setting up my components in unit tests in order to test this logic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general you should use the "new" style component integration tests for this type of thing.

See the following resources:

- [Example from the ember-radio-button addon](https://github.com/yapplabs/ember-radio-button/blob/6862ca38cd0d51810d0eb237e6cb34ac2f3ca2af/tests/unit/components/radio-button-test.js#L211-L241)
- Nice blog post - [Ember component integration tests](http://alisdair.mcdiarmid.org/2015/06/20/ember-component-integration-tests.html)

---

**Update:** Based on the blog post linked from Robert's answer, here is the new test code in `tests/integration/components/global-nav-item-test.js`:

```
import hbs from 'htmlbars-inline-precompile';
import { moduleForComponent, test } from 'ember-qunit';

moduleForComponent('global-nav-item', 'Integration | Component | global-nav-item', {
  integration: true
});

test('has a toggle button if a submenu is present', function(assert) {
  this.render(hbs`
    {{#global-nav-item text="Hello" href="/"}}
      <ul class="le-global-nav-submenu"></ul>
    {{/global-nav-item}}
  `);

  assert.ok(this.$('.global-nav-toggle-submenu').length);
});
```

Comment: This worked for me by moving into a separate integration test file as the blog post instructs. Do you feel that unit tests are no longer needed for components, or is it too early to tell? Or I suppose the integration tests are only needed if you're testing UI elements...